# same SQL Query returining different results

Tags: oracle10g

I have a query like this,

table A data,

```
PK    Fst_Name  Mid_Name Last_Name   Full_NAme 
---------------------------------------------------
1     Peter              Kisnan      Peter,Kisnan
2     Jeff      S        Boycott     Jeff,S,Boycott

select 1,PK,fst_name,Last_Name,Full_Name from A where PK=2
union
select 2, PK,fst_name,Last_Name,Full_Name from A where last_name='Kisnan' and fst_name='Peter'
```

Results

```
1,2,Jeff,Boycott, Jeff,S,Boycott
2,1,Jeff,Boycott, Jeff,S,Boycott
```

Could anyone answer how it is possible? I am usin Oracle 10g

also query

```
select count(1) from A where last_name='Kisnan' and fst_name='Peter' shows 2. but
select count(1) from A where last_name like'%Kisnan' and fst_name like'%Peter' shows 1.
```

Comment: For given query and data, it is not possible but I assume you are not showing us your actually query and data. Just a stab at it, the PK isn't unique and there are two records with PK=2. One for Peter and one for Jeff. Change your `union` to a `union all`. If there's an extra, duplicate row, you have your prove.

Comment: I am sorry the results of my union query is like this,                    1,2,Jeff,Boycott, Jeff,S,Boycott
2,2,Jeff,Boycott, Jeff,S,Boycott

Comment: also the quey select * from A where last_name='Kisnan' and fst_name='Peter' gives me 2, Jeff, S, Boycott,  Jeff,S,Boycott and the query * from A where last_name like'%Kisnan' and fst_name like'%Peter' gives 1,Peter, , Kisnan, Peter,Kisnan.